# How to get contacts for each sub account of a parent account

Tags: report, dynamics-crm-4, crm

A client has a custom report that they want functionality added to for Dynamics CRM 4.0.
Currently, the report is ran from a Parent Account.
When the report is finally generated, it displays the Child Accounts in rows.
In those rows are columns for Primary Contact Job Title, Primary Contact Name, Secondary Contact Job Title, and Secondary Contact Name. These columns are currently empty but they need to be populated.
How can I populate these fields using a dataset query in the report?

Basically it would be  query that would be For Each Sub Account, select the contacts, but I am having a hard time getting this to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible solution in my opinion is to use a [Subreport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581.aspx) which allows you to pass a parameter to another report/query which then gets merged with your report. In this case you would be sending the child account's id as a report parameter. Then in the subreport you build your query for retrieving the child account parameters, and you can access the id you passed as a variable (ie. @ChildAccountID)